# SMTP always fail on first attempt

Tags: email, powershell, windows-server-2012, smtp

I tried PowerShell to test SMTP, but the first attempt or first few attempts will always fail and receive the same error

`Send-MailMessage : Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed`

However, it will become successful after one or several fails, and keep on being successful until I do not run the script for a long time. Like if I do not keep sending emails by using the script for about 30 minutes, the "first attempt" will fail again.

And below is the script I used for testing.

`$creds = get-credential`

`Send-MailMessage –From <O365 email address> –To <Recipient email address> –Subject "Test Email" –Body "Test SMTP Service from Powershell on Port 587" -SmtpServer smtp.office365.com -Credential $creds -UseSsl -Port 587`

I keep pinging smtp.office365.com and telnet port 587 of smtp.office365.com, the connection is fine. And I researched on the internet, other people also having the same error, but their attempts are all failed, unlike mine.

I tried solutions like IIS SMTP binding and set it to All unsigned in https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/7242541e-5722-4064-86bf-a108daf8711a/sendmail-powershell-issues?forum=winserverpowershell , but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/new-opt-in-endpoint-available-for-smtp-auth-clients-still/ba-p/2659652

It seems that Microsoft ended support of TLS1.0 and 1.1 of Exchange Online started from October 2020 caused this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I agree.....but MS must be implenting this change little by little in theirs servers...thats the cause it works from some country and fails from other.

I add this line to my script, and now it works:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'Tls,TLS11,TLS12'
```

from other site, the same scripts works without this line.